# Images are escaping from the help center privilege page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

Images included in the fully expanded privilege pages are escaping from the body.

This is most noticeable on the [retag questions privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/retag-questions) (which I know is going away soon anyway):

[image: Retag Questions Privilege]

But is also apparent on:

- [Cast close and reopen votes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)
- [Access to moderator tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

In the edit page preview, the images sit correctly within the borders.

```
Chrome 27, Windows 7
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed on dev and will be out in the next deployment.